# How to get full CREATE INDEX clause for existing index in pure SQL?

Tags: postgresql

I've wrote a simple script to reindex our PG databases once a week. It has a simple logic:

- get top 10 indices by amount of bloated bytes
- lookup create index clause from hashmap variable (index name -> create clause)

  - if there is none - log to stderr and go to next index
- create new index concurrently
- drop old index concurrently
- rename new index

And being proper lazy developer I dislike this concept that I have to constantly update my hashmap. (On the other hand, I have found two inefficient indices while doing that.)

pg_index seems quite informative, is there a way to reconstruct a create index clause from it?

It's easy to get columns list, but we use different index types, different opclasses for fields, partial indices... And who knows what.
It's important to be sure that we will get exact the same clause that was used to create index in the first place.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yep, there's a built-in function [`pg_get_indexdef`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) for the purpose.

e.g.:

```
regress=> SELECT pg_get_indexdef('demo_pkey'::regclass);
                    pg_get_indexdef                     
--------------------------------------------------------
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX demo_pkey ON demo USING btree (id)
(1 row)
```

Comment: It's really a shame that there isn't an equivalent functions for the definition of a table (`pg_get_tabledef()` would really be useful)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I agree. Extremely strongly. I understand the logic (re downgrades) with making `pg_dump` a client side tool, but the lack of server side DDL export as an option is very frustrating.

Comment: Wow! So glad it actually exists. Even knowing this function description I can't easily google it :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Unfortunately `pg_dump` is spaghetti, and the SPI (the server side equivalent of libpq) isn't enough like `libpq` to make it easy to turn the guts of `pg_dump` into a library that could be used server-side or client-side.